# Python global keyword

Tags: python

I am confused with the global keyword behavior in below code snippet, I was expecting 30, 30, 30 in all 3 prints.

```
def outer_function():
    #global a  ###commented intentionally
    a = 20
    def inner_function():
        global a
        a = 30
        print('a =',a)

    inner_function()
    print('a =',a)

a = 10
outer_function()
print('a =',a)
#Output:
#30
#20  #Expecting 30 here
#30
```

All the confusion coming from "global a" after outer function definition. As my understanding at this point of time is  " All the reference and assignment to variable become globally reflected on declaration of global keyword on that variable". If I am uncommenting that first global statement I am getting expected output 30,30,30.

Why global declaration inside inner_function and value change does not reflect on 2nd print i:e to outer_function(or outer scope), whereas got reflected in global namespace.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're confused about. If you don't use global there, then the reference to `a` in that scope is not global. Why is this surprising?

Comment: Because the second print is not in `inner_function`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common acronym to be familiar with is **LEGB**:

- **L**ocal
- **E**nclosed
- **G**lobal
- **B**uilt-in

This is the order in which Python will search the namespaces to find variable assignments.

### Local

The local namespace is everything that happens within the current code block.  Function definitions contain local variables that are the first thing that is found when Python looks for a variable reference.  Here, Python will look in the local scope of `foo` first, find `x` with the assignment of `2` and print that.  All of this happens despite `x` also being defined in the global namespace.

```
x = 1
def foo():
    x = 2
    print(x)

foo()
# prints:
2
```

When Python compiles a function, it decides whether each of the variables within the definition code block are local or global variables.  Why is this important?  Let's take a look at the same definition of `foo`, but flip the two lines inside of it.  The result can be surprising

```
x = 1
def foo():
    print(x)
    x = 2

foo()
# raises:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

This error occurs because Python compiles `x` as a **local** variable within `foo` due to the assignment of `x = 2`.

What you need to remember is that local variables can only access what is inside of their own scope.

### Enclosed

When defining a multi-layered function, variables that are not compiled as local will search for their values in the next highest namespace.  Here is a simple example.

```
x = 0

def outer_0():
    x = 1
    def outer_1():
        def inner():
            print(x)

        inner()

    outer_1()

outer_0()
# print:
1
```

When `inner()` is compiled, Python sets `x` as a global variable, meaning it will try to access other assignments of `x` outside of the local scope.  The order in which Python searches for a value of x in moving upward through the enclosing namespaces.  `x` is not contained in the namespace of `outer_1`, so it checks `outer_0`, finds a values and uses that assignment for the `x` within `inner`.

```
x --> inner --> outer_1 --> outer_0 [ --> global, not reached in this example]
```

You can force a variable to not be local using the keywords `nonlocal` and `global` (note: `nonlocal` is only available in Python 3).  These are directives to the compiler about the variable scope.

#### `nonlocal`

Using the `nonlocal` keyword tells python to assign the variable to first instance found as it moves upward through the namespaces.  Any changes made to the variable will be made in the variable's original namespace as well.  In the example below, when `2` is assigned `x`, it is setting the value of `x` in the scope of `outer_0` as well.

```
x = 0

def outer_0():
    x = 1
    def outer_1():
        def inner():
            nonlocal x
            print('inner  :', x)
            x = 2
        inner()
    outer_1()
    print('outer_0:', x)

outer_0()
# prints:
inner  : 1
outer_0: 2
```

### Global

The global namespace is the highest level namespace that you program is running in.  It is also the highest enclosing namespace for all function definitions.  In general it is not good practice to pass values in and out of variables in the global namespace as unexpected side effects can occur.

#### `global`

Using the `global` keyword is similar to non-local, but instead of moving upward through the namespace layers, it ***only*** searches in the global namespace for the variable reference.  Using the same example from above, but in this case declaring `global x` tells Python to use the assignment of `x` in the global namespace.  Here the global namespace has `x = 0`:

```
x = 0

def outer_0():
    x = 1
    def outer_1():
        def inner():
            global x
            print('inner  :', x)
        inner()
    outer_1()

outer_0()
# prints:
0
```

Similarly, if a variable is not yet defined in the global namespace, it will raise an error.

```
def foo():
    z = 1
    def bar():
        global z
        print(z)
    bar()

foo()
# raises:
NameError: name 'z' is not defined
```

### Built-in

Last of all, Python will check for built-in keywords.  Native Python functions such as `list` and `int` are the final reference Python checks for **AFTER** checking for variables.  You can overload native Python functions (but please don't do this, it is a bad idea).

Here is an example of something you SHOULD NOT DO.  In `dumb` we overload the the native Python `list` function by assigning it to `0` in the scope of `dumb`.  In the `even_dumber`, when we try to split the string into a list of letters using `list`, Python will find the reference to `list` in the enclosing namespace of `dumb` and try to use that, raising an error.

```
def dumb():
    list = 0
    def even_dumber():
        x = list('abc')
        print(x)
    even_dumber()

dumb()
# raises:
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

You can get back the original behavior by referencing the global definition of `list` using:

```
def dumb():
    list = [1]
    def even_dumber():
        global list
        x = list('abc')
        print(x)
    even_dumber()

dumb()
# returns:
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

But again, DO NOT DO THIS, it is bad coding practice.

I hope this helps bring to light some of how the namespaces work in Python.  If you want more information, chapter 7 of Fluent Python by Luciano Ramalho has a wonderful in-depth walkthrough of namespaces and closures in Python.

Comment: @James-Thanks a Ton. A really REALLY helpful Answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire
>   current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be
>   interpreted as globals.

Note it only applies to current code block. So the `global` in `inner_function` only applies within `inner_function`. Outside of it, the identifier is not global.

Note how “identifier” is not the same as “variable”. So what it tells the interpreter is *“when I use identifier `a` within this code block, do not apply normal scope resolution, I actually mean the module-level variable, ”*.

Answer (score 1):

Just uncomment your global command in the outer_function, otherwise you're declaring a local variable with value 20, changing a global variable then printing that same local variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea use global variabilities. If you want only reset the value of a variable, you just use this lines:

```
def outer_function():
a = 20
def inner_function():
         a = 30
         print('a =',a)
         return a

    a = inner_function()
    print('a =',a)
    return a

a = 10
a = outer_function()
print('a =',a)
```